# Encrypt Elements Inside MongoDB Documents

Tags: php, mongodb, encryption

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [MongoDB database encryption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8803332/mongodb-database-encryption)

I am storing sensitive data (server details) into `MongoDB` and `MySQL`, thankfully with MySQL I can simply use `AES_ENCRYPT()` and `AES_DECRYPT()` when storing the data at the column query level. How can I replicate this functionality with MongoDB?

Currently I don't see a native way to encrypt/decrypt documents. Do I have to do the encryption/decryption at the application level? How would this even look assuming I am using PHP and have something like:

```
Array
(
  [servers] => Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [id] => srv_MvffqtLdit4fad9bdecba8dwuDUy
                [label] => WEB1
                [address] => web1.domain.com
                [ssh_username] => root
                [ssh_port] => 3050
                [added] => 2012-05-11 16:08:14
                [modified] => 2012-05-11 16:08:14
            )
        [1] => stdClass Object
            (
                [id] => srv_Omkb8x2gOF4fbd8e86aceffaKHnA
                [label] => WEB2
                [address] => web2.domain.com
                [ssh_username] => root
                [ssh_port] => 3050
                [added] => 2012-05-23 18:27:34
                [modified] => 2012-05-23 18:27:34
            )

    )
)
```

The data keys I wish to encrypt are only `address, ssh_username, ssh_port`.

Thanks.

Comment: read this , it might help http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/3026/encrypting-with-mongo

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8803332/mongodb-database-encryption ... this is same thing

Answer (score 2):

Encryption of MongoDB-related data is soley up to you and your application. There is nothing where MongoDB will help you in any way.

[MongoDB database encryption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8803332/mongodb-database-encryption)

https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/3026/encrypting-with-mongo