# MongoDB $near with encrypted gps data?

Tags: mongodb, encryption, gps

I'm trying to use MongoDB **$near** function with user GPS(Location) data.

1. MongoDB doesn't support DB encryption.
2. Therefore, if i want to encrypt data, encrypt data on the client side.
3. In that case, I cannot use $near function.

Q1. How can I use $near function in encrypted data?

Q2. In U.S. user GPS data must have encrypted?

Comment: This looks like a total mess. Make your question readable.

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8803332/mongodb-database-encryption) answer. In short: no you cant encrypt locations like that and then query it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> MongoDB doesn't support DB encryption.

As at MongoDB 2.4, there is no built-in support for encryption of data at rest.  The [Security](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/security/) section of the MongoDB manual covers other aspects of security such as encrypting the data sent over the network as well as access and network control.

> Therefore, if i want to encrypt data, encrypt data on the client side.

If you want to encrypt the data in flight, you could use SSL support and follow other best practices for securing your MongoDB deployment.

If you want to encrypt the data at rest, there are complementary open source and commercial products that can provide transparent disk or key-based encryption for MongoDB.  Some examples: Linux Unified Key Setup (LUKS), Gazzang, TrueCrypt, BitLocker.

> In that case, I cannot use $near function.

If you use one of the aforementioned "transparent" encryption products you can have full access to MongoDB's geospatial functionality.  From the MongoDB server's point of view it is reading data from a block device and does not need to understand the encryption.

If you want to encrypt the geospatial coordinates *within* a MongoDB document, you will not be able to build any useful geo indexes on the encrypted lat/long values.

> In U.S. user GPS data must have encrypted?

I'm not aware of this requirement.  You could always separate "geospatial" data (latitude and longitude) needed for searches from the full GPS data (lat/long/altitude/satellite?) and apply some some of encryption in your application for the "extra sensitive" data.